# Push Notifications not working on iOS 4

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4, ios5, apple-push-notifications

I have asked this question on the Apple DevForums, too.

If I get an answer there, I'll share it here, too.

The problem is:

We have installed the same AdHoc app on our iOS 4 (good thing that we didn't update all of them to iOS 5) and iOS 5 devices.

The PN is received on the iOS 5 device, but nothing happens on iOS 4.

We triple checked everything on the server, in the app and on the devices. Still it works only on iOS 5.

Did anyone encounter this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: can you post the link to the apple dev forums? Have you got any answers till now?

Answer (score 1):

Also you will not receive Push notification if your iPhone is jail-breaked.

And it's good idea to check are you using developing or production certificate and device token.

Comment: it is not truth, that a jailbroken iPhone cannot get Push Notifications. Why shouldnt it?

Comment: It's my experience. Maybe they have more problems while receiving Push. it could depend on jailbreak type, don't know.

Comment: It depends on hactivating, but there is a fix for that and then you will get notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check wether you use the right APN certificates?

You should make sure that you use the right certificate to the right address.
The sandbox mode is not the same as release mode. So you will get from the apple server 2 different push token.

To make sure wether you are doing correctly, I suggest you to try http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/programming-apple-push-notification-services

Sometimes the Push also delays till 1 hour. Keep this in mind.